Why am I getting error: "C2731: 'wWinMain' : function cannot be overloaded"?
I am getting this error in my program :

error C2731: 'wWinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

at this line:
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInst, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hprevInst, _In_ LPCWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)

I have found out that there is a same function declared in WinBase.h in this macro:

WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

Which is just:

((100 == 100))

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
A lot of similar problems are with having normal string instead of wide string, but from what I have understand, this should work just fine.

I just found out that the command line string can't be constant so it should be:
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInst, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hprevInst, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)

i.e. replacing the LPCWSTR with LPWSTR.

The answer would be more helpful if you explained why the original function declaration caused an error.

Please don't forget to accept your answer.
